# How can I make particles flow like lava, like in the Intro to the Rings of Power

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

[image: particle set up using simple children]

I'm trying to make a section of the particles flow like lava for close up shots. Like how they animated the particles in rings of power intro. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
I've tried using force fields and collision objects but my particles move and stop instantly when hit instead of gradually slowing down.